# Is this true ? $a^3c \pmod{ab} = a^3c \pmod{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is this true ? $a^3c \pmod{ab} = a^3c \pmod{b}$

Actually I was working on this and got confused in my previous question... This seems to be true...Is it easy to verify/prove ? Thanks!

---

$a | a^3c$

im thinking $a$ should not matter for the remainder but not really sure

Comment: @qwr please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b<a^3c<ab$, then $a^3c\pmod{ab}=a^3c\neq a^3c\pmod{b}$

Comment: $\mod{}$ is an equivalence relation so you cannot say that $a^3c\pmod{ab}=a^3c$ just as you cannot say that $2\pmod{5}=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say,  $b=a^3$ and $c=1$  then,

$$a^3 \,mod\,{a^4}=a^3$$ $$and$$ $$a^3  \,mod\, {a^3}=0$$

Hence not equal for $a\neq0$.

Comment: The initial unedited answer gave a more general counter-example, namely $b=a^3, a\nmid c$.